# Mobile navigation click out jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I  have a function that when a user clicks outside of the mobile navigation close the mobile menu. I don't think I've got the code just right as when I click the mobile menu it opens and closes straight away.
What I want to happen is when the user clicks outside of the nav slideToggle the menu back.

Current code is:

```
    // Responsive menu
$('.mobile-menu').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('nav').slideToggle('slow');
});
// Close out the menu on click outside
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
    var box = document.getElementById('nav');
    if(event.target != box && event.target.parentNode != box) {
        $('nav').slideToggle('slow');
    }
});
```

I think it's somewhere to do with mouseup however I don't see a mouseclick in the available parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you `mousedown` on `.mobile-menu` it shows the `nav`, then when you `mouseup` on anything outside the `nav`, including `.mobile-menu`, it hides the `nav` again. You should check that the click event's target also isn't `.mobile-menu`. Try the following code:

```
// Responsive menu
$('.mobile-menu').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('nav').slideToggle('slow');
});
// Close out the menu on click outside
$(window).on('mouseup', function(event) {
    if(!$(event.target).is("nav") && $.contains(event.target, $("nav")) && !$(event.target).is('.mobile-menu')) {
        $('nav').slideToggle('slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Anywhere I click in the window it toggles the nav down.

Comment: @Jolen Updated, try now.

Comment: Now the code doesn't toggle when you click outside the nav

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a cleaner approach to this.
The window's listener should only be bound after the menu is expanded. When it's collapsed, the listener should be removed. This will prevent a lot of hassle and possible bug due to asynchronous execution of 2 event listeners.
With that in mind:

```
// First we define a callback function to be called after the nav complete showing, which will close the nav when a user tap outside.
var bindEventListener = function(event) {
    var box = document.getElementById('nav');
    if(event.target != box && event.target.parentNode != box) {
        $('nav').slideUp('slow', function(){
            // remove the window's event listener after the nav is closed
            window.removeEventListener('mouseup', bindEventListener);
        });
    }
});

// Now we set the button's onclick event and bind the above defined callback for mouseup event.
$('.mobile-menu').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('nav').slideDown('slow', function(){
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', bindEventListener);
    });
});
```

Comment: Anywhere I click in the window it toggles the nav down.

Answer (score 0):

The target of the click event is not necessarily the `nav` or it's first level child, so if there is a click event on the `nav` you will slide it open and then slide it close.

You need to check if the `nav` contains the target element or equals to it, so inside the event listener, change your condition to this:

```
if(!(event.target == box || $.contains(box, event.target))) {
  ...
```